# Scale a billboard matrix in DX11

Tags: c++, math, matrix, directx, rendering

I have constructed a billboard matrix using the code below:

```
    XMFLOAT4X4 translationMatrix = XMFLOAT4X4();
    translationMatrix._11 = right.x;    translationMatrix._21 = up.x;   translationMatrix._31 = look.x; translationMatrix._41 = worldposition.x;
    translationMatrix._12 = right.y;    translationMatrix._22 = up.y;   translationMatrix._32 = look.y; translationMatrix._42 = worldposition.y;
    translationMatrix._13 = right.z;    translationMatrix._23 = up.z;   translationMatrix._33 = look.z; translationMatrix._43 = worldposition.z;
    translationMatrix._14 = 0;          translationMatrix._24 = 0;   translationMatrix._34 = 0;    translationMatrix._44 = 1;
```

And this works correctly, however I want the billboard to be scalable, how can I achieve this as the matrix is entirely vectors and thus isn't inherently scalable?

Trying to scale using `XMMatrixScaleFromVector()` causes the billboard to start moving when the camera approaches it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) functions ``Matrix::CreateBillboard`` and ``Matrix::CreateConstrainedBillboard`` ([source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SimpleMath.inl))

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I would however I'm not using DirectXTK for this particular project, in future I probably will though as it looks a lot more complete than what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of what you're doing is correct, then `right`, `up`, and `look` simply represent the world-space base vectors of the local coordinate system of the billboard. In this case, it should be sufficient to just scale the `right` and `up` vectors (assuming those correspond to the *x* and *y* axes of the billboard) to your heart's desire and that's all there is to it…

Comment: Thank you, this worked and makes much more sense than altering the size of the plane like I've heard from other suggestions.